# Web api not binding correctly to html format in Angular

Tags: angular

I have data coming in from a web api in this format:

```
    {
      "result": [
        {
          "location.city": "xxxx",
          "location.country": "xxxx",
          "location.street": "xxxxxx",
        },
     ]
}
```

When I try to bind it to my view I am doing the following:

**ts file**

```
this.selectedStreet = selectedObj.location.street;
```

html:

```
[(ngModel)]="selectedStreet"
```

But nothing shows up? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a problem just with the typescript code here, `selectedObj.location.street` is not what you want it should be `selectedObj['location.street']`.

To elaborate on this a bit, an object such as this is totally valid:

```
{
  "location": {
    "street": "xxxxx"
  },
  "location.street": "yyyyy"
}
```

And so you would access the different properties like so:

```
obj.location.street // xxxxx
obj['location'].street // xxxxx
obj['location']['street'] // xxxxx
obj['location.street'] // yyyyy
```